# How can i change the width of the image from the nth class using a script?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div class="curbaT">
        <img src="avertizare/1.png" class="img" >
        <p class="p1">Curba la stanga </p>
</div>

.img{
   left: 10px;
   height: 100px;
   width: 120px;
   margin-top: auto;
   margin-bottom: auto;
   position: absolute;
}
```

I have several such divs (multiple classes "curbaT") and I want the image of the 2th, 6th, 7th, 15th and 22th div to be 150 wide.

I don't know javascript, just html and css, but this is what i would like to do using a script. From what I understood, you can select anything and change the respective characteristics. Thx!

Comment: couldn't you use something like this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:nth-child(n)` selector. [Reference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

```css
.curbaT:nth-child(1) img,
.curbaT:nth-child(3) img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="curbaT"><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/30" /></div>
<div class="curbaT"><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/30" /></div>
<div class="curbaT"><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/30" /></div>
<div class="curbaT"><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/30" /></div>
```